# WordPress Category Metadata

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am making a plugin , for which I have to save meta data of Cateogry , where should I save it?

One option is saving it in wp_postmeta , and set meta key comment_meta . This would work, but it will be illogical.

Need Better Solution

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin you could use:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-category-meta/

Or you could use the "Settings API":

https://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_API